# Integration of $f(x)=(-1)^n(n+1)1_{(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac1n]}(x)$ over $[c,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

> [image]

Could anyone explain why is the last equality true?

Comment: Is there a typo somewhere? $f$ does not depend on $x$, so that the integrand is just a constant.

Comment: You may find it helpful to draw approximately what $f$ looks like.

Comment: @parsiad The following phrase takes care of that.  $f(x)=\begin{cases} (-1)^1(1+1)&\text{for} ~x\in (\frac{1}{1+1},\frac{1}{1}]\\(-1)^2(2+1)&\text{for}~x\in (\frac{1}{2+1},\frac{1}{2}]\\\vdots\end{cases}$

Comment: $f(x)$ is a piecewise constant function, so the integral just becoming the (Riemann) sum.

Comment: @parsiad I don't think it's a typo. f(x) is a constant $(-1)^n(n+1)$ just OVER the interval $(1/(n+1), 1/n]$.

Comment: And this integral can be easily solved by transforming it into a sum of finitely many integrals

Comment: Thanks. I was confused by the presentation; didn't realize we were still defining $f$ on the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, take the integral from $c$ to $\frac{1}{N}$. $f(x)=(-1)^N(N+1)$ on this interval, which is a constant, so we get $(-1)^N(N+1)\left(\frac 1 N-c\right)$. That takes care of the first term.

Now, we have to go from $\frac{1}{N}$ to $\frac{1}{N-1}$, from the latter to $\frac{1}{N-2}$, from that to $\frac{1}{N-3}$, ..., from $\frac{1}{2}$ to $\frac{1}{1}$. That's a lot to deal with, so let's just say we're going from $\frac{1}{k+1}$ to $\frac{1}{k}$. On this interval, we get that $f(x)=(-1)^k(k+1)$, which is a constant, so the integral over this interval is just $(-1)^k(k+1)\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)$, which can be simplified to:
$$(-1)^k(k+1)\left(\frac{(k+1)-k}{k(k+1)}\right)=(-1)^k\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)=\frac{(-1)^k}{k}$$
Now, remember, we want to go to do this starting from the interval $\frac{1}{N}$ to $\frac{1}{N-1}$ and ending at the interval $\frac{1}{2}$ to $\frac{1}{1}$. The above interval represents $\frac{1}{k+1}$ to $\frac 1 k$, so if we sum the above from $k=N-1$ to $k=1$ (or the other way around), we'll get the rest of the integral, which takes care of the second term.

Comment: Nice answer (+1).